# Python lambda function if else condition

Tags: python, pandas

**Question**: Trying to understand someone else's code. Can someone please explain what the lambda function is doing here?. Does the lambda function here translates to: If the first 3 digits of `OrderNumber` are not `486` and not `561`, and the first digit is not `8` then set the column value  `data_df[OrderNumber]` of the `dataframe` to empty string; otherwise leave it as it is?

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/CustomerOrders.txt', sep=',', low_memory=False, quotechar='"', header='infer' , encoding='cp1252')

data_df[OrderNumber] = data_df[OrderNumber].apply(lambda x: x if x[:3] != '486' and x[:3] != '561' and x[:1] != '8' else "")
.............
.............
```

Comment: You have it backwards. It leaves it as is when the `if` condition is true, otherwise it's the empty string.

Comment: Just read `else` as `otherwise` and it should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lambda x: x if x[:3] != '486' and x[:3] != '561' and x[:1] != '8' else ""` essentially translates to:

```
if x[:3] != '486' and x[:3] != '561' and x[:1] != '8':
    return x
else:
    return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it backwards if the condition evaluates to True (which will occur in the instances you describe) the entry will be unchanged, if any of those equalities are met the condition evaluates to False and the entry is made to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It filtered all orders which OrderNumber startswith `('486', '561', '8')` and set their number to empty string `""`

I guess these OrderNumbers are not valid or not useful for current situation.